# Query to get difference between the current date and minimum date for that id

Tags: sql, oracle

I have written this sql query.It's not working, it says

> from keyword NOT found where not expected

Where am I going wrong? My date format is in `DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS`. I am using Oracle database.

```
 SELECT dr1.pod_id, current_date() - dr1.daily_reading_date 
 FROM (
     SELECT pod_id, 
            MIN(daily_reading_date) mindate 
     FROM  daily_data_reading
     GROUP BY pod_id
      ) mini
 INNER JOIN daily_data_reading dr1
     ON  dr1.pod_id = mini.pod_id 
     AND dr1.daily_reading_date = mini.mindate
```

Comment: `SYSDATE-dr1.daily_reading_date `

Comment: It should be `current_date` not `current_date()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle Support `CURRENT_DATE / SYSDATE`  not `current_date()`

```
SELECT dr1.pod_id, SYSDATE - dr1.daily_reading_date 
 FROM (
     SELECT pod_id, 
            MIN(daily_reading_date) mindate 
     FROM  daily_data_reading
     GROUP BY pod_id
      ) mini
 INNER JOIN daily_data_reading dr1
     ON  dr1.pod_id = mini.pod_id 
     AND dr1.daily_reading_date = mini.mindate
```

(OR)

```
SELECT dr1.pod_id, CURRENT_DATE - dr1.daily_reading_date 
 FROM (
     SELECT pod_id, 
            MIN(daily_reading_date) mindate 
     FROM  daily_data_reading
     GROUP BY pod_id
      ) mini
 INNER JOIN daily_data_reading dr1
     ON  dr1.pod_id = mini.pod_id 
     AND dr1.daily_reading_date = mini.mindate
```

Answer (score 0):

And without self-join. 
[FIRST, LAST](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions056.htm)

```
select pod_id,
 CURRENT_DATE - MIN(daily_reading_date) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY daily_reading_date) OVER (PARTITION BY pod_id) "LowestDateGroupedBYID"
 from 
 daily_data_reading
```